# Generate Oulook Email From Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, outlook, interop, openxml

I have an ASP.NET site that needs to be able to dynamically generate an email that will get sent back to the users local machine to then be sent via Outlook. The code below does just that but it uses the Outlook Interop to create the message and I was a bit hesitent to use Interop on a Web App. I looked into OpenXML but couldnt seem to find much on Outlook.

```
            // Creates a new Outlook Application Instance
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application objOutlook = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();

        // Creating a new Outlook Message from the Outlook Application Instance
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem mic = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)(objOutlook.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem));

        mic.To = "to@email.com";
        mic.CC = "cc@email.com";
        mic.Subject = "Test Subject";
        mic.HTMLBody = "Test Message Body";


        string strNewEmailPath = strEmailPath + "\\EmailMessages\\" + strUser + "_Message_PEI.msg";

        mic.SaveAs(strNewEmailPath, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlSaveAsType.olMSG);

        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-outlook";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Message.msg");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.TransmitFile(strNewEmailPath);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

Can anyone help with perhaps a better suggestion for automating an Outlook message using ASP.NET?

**Update:**

I did find the Javascript code which seems do have similar functionality.

```
var theApp    //Reference to Outlook.Application 
var theMailItem   //Outlook.mailItem
//Attach Files to the email, Construct the Email including     
//To(address),subject,body
var subject = sub
var msg = body
//Create a object of Outlook.Application
try
{
    var theApp = new ActiveXObject("Outlook.Application")
    var theMailItem = theApp.CreateItem(0) // value 0 = MailItem
      //Bind the variables with the email
      theMailItem.to = to
      theMailItem.Subject = (subject);
      theMailItem.Body = (msg);
      //Show the mail before sending for review purpose
      //You can directly use the theMailItem.send() function
      //if you do not want to show the message.
      theMailItem.display()
  }
catch(err)
{
    alert("Error");
}
```

Comment: You should generate the MIME file directly, without Outlook.

Comment: Any sample code on how this is done? Outlook's .msg files are not text based.

Comment: If that JavaScript works for you, then put it as an answer (not as part of the question). If it doesn't work, then explain why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did find the Javascript code which seems do have similar functionality. I was hoping someone might have an OpenXML solution but this JS solution can work and is better than Outlook Interop

```
var theApp    //Reference to Outlook.Application 
var theMailItem   //Outlook.mailItem
//Attach Files to the email, Construct the Email including     
//To(address),subject,body
var subject = sub
var msg = body
//Create a object of Outlook.Application
try
{
    var theApp = new ActiveXObject("Outlook.Application")
    var theMailItem = theApp.CreateItem(0) // value 0 = MailItem
      //Bind the variables with the email
      theMailItem.to = to
      theMailItem.Subject = (subject);
      theMailItem.Body = (msg);
      //Show the mail before sending for review purpose
      //You can directly use the theMailItem.send() function
      //if you do not want to show the message.
      theMailItem.display()
  }
catch(err)
{
    alert("Error");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar need before. I shelved the idea because of the complexity of generating [.msg](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc463912.aspx) files (though I think there's [some commercial libraries](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/emailnet/Creating+and+Saving+Outlook+Message+(MSG)+Files) that can do it). One alternative you may consider is installing an Outlook add-in on the user's machine. Poll the web server (or this would be a great case for [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) so the server could push data) and have the web server send the details of the email to the user's machine. Then the add-in could generate the email based on the details it received from the server. This would avoid running Interop on the server (which is a **bad** idea). However, you'll now have the complexity of deploying an Outlook Add-In, but if this is a corporate environment it shouldn't be too difficult.

If you didn't want to do it as an add-in, you could still do it by just writing a service application that runs on the user's machine and uses Interop, but that still has all the complexities of the add-in technique.

Alternatively, if your email is really simple, you could just [use a mailto URI](https://yoast.com/guide-mailto-links/). But I find them very limiting, since it's difficult or impossible to send an HTML message that way.

And lastly, you could have the server just send the email on the user's behalf, not involving code running on the user's machine at all.

Comment: Unfortunatley I have quite a few restrictions for whats on both the web server and on the users machine. Also this message is very dynamic so simple mailto wont cut it. Finally the user MUST be able to review, further cutomize and then encrypt the email.